# netcore.app - no compatible framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a web application set with Target framework .NETCoreApp1.1

It works when I run locally, but when I publish to the server (I'm working remotely and can't web publish - instead I publish to file system, zip the file and extract on the server)

When I start in IIS it fails with:

"Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MYAPP' with physical root 'D:\Websites\MyApp\' failed to start process with commandline '"dotnet" .\MyApp.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 80008083.

Running manually from my app folder

"dotnet ./MyApp.dll"

It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.1.1' was not found.
 - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at: \
 - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.1.1'.

In C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk:

- 1.0.1
- 1.0.4

In C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App:

- 1.0.4
- 1.0.5
- 1.1.1
- 1.1.2
- 2.0.0

Can anyone explain what I might be missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update .NET Core SDK ≥ 1.1.1:
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md#net-core-11

If your project allows, update your application to .NET Core 2.0 instead – you may require VS 2017.

Comment: Did you install both 1.1.4?

Comment: Yep, in the sdk folder I have 1.1.4 and in the Microsoft.netcore.app folder i have 1.1.4

Comment: I haven't restarted - can't do that until 5pm.  Will try later today and reply once I do.  Thanks

Comment: As a last ditch, I changed the project to .net core 2.0 and deployed - that worked.  So while my issue wasn't fixed, the problem has gone away.  thanks for your help @aaron

Comment: No problem - complete oversight on my part!

Answer (score 0):

Updating my web application to .NET Core 2.0 from 1.1 and then redeploying has resolved my issue